# php get id to delete record

Tags: php, mysql

PHP beginner on line:).
I have two files (viewKands.php-listing records and izbrisi.php-for deleting records from database. I try to delete record from db(upisi). But no luck.
Here is the code...Where is my mistake?

**viewKands.php:**

```
 $kon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "upisi");
        $kon->set_charset("utf8");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            echo "Greska pri konekcija so baza: " . mysql_error();
        }
$sqlView = "SELECT idPrijava,brPrijava,jazik,struka,profil,imeKand,tatIme,"
                . "prezKand from tblprijava ";
        $result = mysqli_query($kon, $sqlView);
        $rBr = 1;
while ($rowV = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $rowV["idPrijava"];
  echo "<tr><td>" . $rBr . "</td><td>" . $rowV["brPrijava"] . "</td><td>" . $rowV["jazik"] . "</td><td>" . $rowV["struka"] .
                "</td><td>" . $rowV["profil"] . "</td><td>" . $rowV["imeKand"] . " " . $rowV["tatIme"] . " " . $rowV["prezKand"] .
                "</td><td><a href='uredi.php'>Уреди</a></td>" . " <td><a href='izbrisi.php?id=$id'>X</a></td>" . "</td></tr>";
                $rBr++;
            }
```

And **izbrisi.php (for deleting records)**

```
$delkon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","upisi");
$delkon->set_charset("utf8");
if (isset($_GET["idPrijava"]) != "") {
    $delete = $_GET["idPrijava"];
    $dqry = "DELETE FROM tblprijava WHERE idPrijava='$delete'";
    $delete = mysqli_query($delkon, $dqry);

    if ($delkon->query($dqry) === TRUE) {
        header("Location:viewKands.php");
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($delete);
    }
} else {
    echo "ID error";
}
$delkon->close();
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What do you mean by no luck?  Are you receiving error messages?  Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Welcome and please visit this guide to improve the quality your question and the chances of getting the right answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide the error messages if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code to **izbrisi.php**

```
$delkon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","upisi");
$delkon->set_charset("utf8");
if (isset($_GET["id"]) != "") {
    $delete = $_GET["id"];
    $dqry = "DELETE FROM tblprijava WHERE idPrijava='$delete'";
    $delete = mysqli_query($delkon, $dqry);

    if ($delkon->query($dqry) === TRUE) {
        header("Location:viewKands.php");
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($delete);
    }
} else {
    echo "ID error";
}
$delkon->close();
```